# Detect sticker selection in MSStickerBrowserView

Tags: ios, swift, imessage

I have built an iMessage app by following a tutorial on the net. Now I want to detect the index of sticker which is tapped. Is there any function like didselect in `MSStickerBrowserView`?

```
extension StickerBrowserViewController {

  override func numberOfStickers(in stickerBrowserView: MSStickerBrowserView) -> Int {
    return stickers.count
  }

  override func stickerBrowserView(_ stickerBrowserView: MSStickerBrowserView, stickerAt index: Int) -> MSSticker {
    return stickers[index]
  }
}
```